# how does timedelta64[s] function works in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

below is link to my min dataset values

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTwlg.png]

my timedeltah64[s] function is giving me wrong answers can someone explain to me where im going wrong with it

```py
z =(data.iloc[1,8:9]-data.iloc[2,8:9]).astype('timedelta64[s]')
print(z)
```

result i'm getting

```
Time   -177.0
dtype: float64
```

instead of 3 seconds

Comment: To note: `timedelta64[s]` is not a function, it is a type.

Comment: It's hard to explain where you go wrong if you don't state what you intend to achiev. What is the input, what your expected output, what the actual output you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problems might be that you use `iloc` with `1` and `2`. Since `iloc` is 0 indexed, you are actually subtracting the second row and the third row.

To get difference of consecutive rows, you can use `diff()` function

```py
data['Time'].diff().astype('timedelta64[s]')
```